# Пустое значение (NULL) или отдельная таблица?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, проектирование, таблицы

Есть таблица в которой фиксируются все операции связанные с расходами.
Есть расход относится к типу "Аванс", то также необходимо сохранять айди аванса, который хранится в другой таблице с соответствующей информацией. 
Для всех других типов расходов поле аванс_ид будет содержать значение NULL.
Это хорошая практика или лучше вынести эту информацию в отдельную таблицу? Если да, то почему?

Comment: Один атрибут - одно поле. Тип расхода "Аванс" - ни разу не сущность, так что какая отдельная таблица?

Comment: А если бы было два и более атрибутов, относящихся исключительно к типу "Аванс"?

Comment: И что? было бы два и более полей. Да, есть случаи, когда возможно (а иногда даже целесообразно) вертикальное разделение на две и более таблиц со связью 1:1 (Вы же на это намекаете?), но это явно не тот случай.

Comment: Да, на связь 1:1. Так как если таких типов как "Аванс" будет много, то таблица станет огромной с полями под каждый тип.
Получается, для таких случаев лучше вообще не использовать реляционные БД?

Comment: "Возможно" - не значит "целесообразно". И уж тем более не значит "обязательно". *если таких типов как "Аванс" будет много* Применительно к описываемой предметной области это скорее всего будет максимум одна (возможно, разреженная) таблица, хранящая частные атрибуты для любого типа платежа, включая и собственно тип. *Получается, для таких случаев ...* Нет.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.
А можете, пожалуйста, привести пример случая, когда имеет смысл разделить таблицу на несколько со связью 1:1?

Comment: *когда имеет смысл разделить таблицу на несколько со связью 1:1?* Основных случаев два. Первый - имеется несколько групп пользователей, часть должны иметь доступ ко всем данным таблицы, остальные лишь к нескольким полям. Эти несколько полей выносятся в отдельную таблицу, и на эти две таблицы раздаются разные права доступа - вторая группа не имеет доступа к таблице с полями, которые этой группе должны быть недоступны. Второй случай - подавляющее большинство запросов идёт лишь к части полей - в этом случае разделение ускоряет работу за счёт того, что таблица более компактна.